# lightningchartJS BUG report: waveform in realtime application freeze every once in a while

Tags: lightningchart

I find a common issue in real time demos in LightningChart JS website ：the waveform will have a short freeze moment every once in a while, is it a BUG or what can we do to fix this issue?

demo1:https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0501-dashboard5chs1000pps.html

demo2:https://github.com/Arction/lcjs-showcase-audio

Answer (score 0):

The freezes are caused by JS garbage collector doing garbage collection. From application code you can only try to minimize how much data you are making the garbage collector collect. We are continuously trying to improve how much the LightningChart JS library itself is loading the JS garbage collector to reduce how much the freezes happen.